# Send image using sockets in C#

Tags: c#, image, sockets, send, .net-micro-framework

i am trying to send raw image from server to client using sockets in NETMF, but with no success.

Here is my server side code, i am sending an image byte[] array using a chunks method, because of buffer size limitations in NETMF:

```
 if (serverSocket.IsConnected)
                    {
                        Byte[] bytesToSend = capturedata;
                        Byte[] outboundBuffer = new byte[512];


                        int incomingOffset = 0;

                        while (incomingOffset < bytesToSend.Length)
                        {
                            int length = System.Math.Min(outboundBuffer.Length, bytesToSend.Length - incomingOffset);                                                            
                            Array.Copy(bytesToSend, incomingOffset, outboundBuffer, 0, length);
                            incomingOffset += length;

                            // Transmit outbound buffer
                            serverSocket.SendBinary(outboundBuffer);

                        }
```

Here is my client side code. I am trying to prepare image from memorystream and show it in picturebox:

```
  public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {


        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {

            memorystream.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            if (bytesRead<=0)
            {

                PICTUREBOX_CAPTURED_IMAGE.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memorystream);// Here is an ArgumentException

            }

            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont know what the matter, but it seems like the server side chunks buffers not completely writes to memorystream on client side, because Byte[] bytesToSend = capturedata; all the time is about 12540 bytes, but when i start to investigate this value on clientside memory stream capacity is about 3500-4600 bytes. And i think because of it i have an Argument Exception when i am trying to make a Bitmap image from stream in this line of code:

```
 if (bytesRead<=0)
            {

                PICTUREBOX_CAPTURED_IMAGE.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memorystream);// Here is an ArgumentException

            }
```

Help me please to find out what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just a hunch, try setting the position of your memorystream to 0 so it reads from the start. `memorystream.Position = 0;` right before you try creating/assigning the image.

Comment: It does not help. it throws the same Argument exception

Comment: Resetting the stream position is a good idea regardless. Also try saving the data using `File.WriteAllBytes("dump.jpg", memorystream.ToArray())` and inspect the file (assuming jpg here, dunno what format you're using). It might give you a clue. Also does the argument exception carry a message? Who knows it may be a cross thread operation failure.

Comment: I tried to writeAllBytes, but cannot open jpg file, something goes wrong. Please advice me some more steps..

Comment: The return value of EndReceive() is just **length of received data** just now. You should not confirm whether there are more data or not. Even if you receive data, which length is larger than 0, it can be last data. But your code doesn't consider it.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I followed your advice, but can't still get an image from stream.. Now i have more bytes on client side than i sended from server side. For example if server sended 13072 bytes, client memorystream length is about 16984 bytes.. what is wrong with it.. I double checked the server side algorithm and it's working as expected..

Comment: Does anybody can advice me wich steps should i do to achieve a result?